# SQLite on C# Cross-Platform Applications

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, orm, mono

Can someone help/guide me with using SQLite lib on Linux (MONO) and Windows (.NET)

On linux i use native mono sqlite client, and on windows i use http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/

is there a way to define 'using' directives like this :

```
#if (linux)
  using Mono.Data.Sqlite;
#else
  using System.Data.SQLite;
```

Another problem is small differencies on both implementations, like :

```
cmd = new SqliteCommand(); // mono
cmd = new SQLiteCommand(); // sqlite.phxsoftware.com
```

Waiting for any help

If you know **better** or simplier way to do this it'll very thankfull for info.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you use 2 different assemblies to perform the same stuff?

Comment: there's no Mono.Data.Sqlite on .net, so i had to. phxsoftware.com somehow didn't want to load under linux.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [csharp-sqlite](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/) which is a port to C# of Sql-Lite.  It is very active and based on 3.6.22 version of SqlLite.  See Miguel's [comments](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Aug-06.html) on attempts to try to speed it up.

Comment: +1, just wanted to add that so far the project seems active and they keep up to date w/ SQLite versions.

Comment: Unfortunately, the current version (being from August 2011) is for SQLite 3.7.7.1, while the current version of SQLite is 3.8.4.3.

Answer (score 4):

I've recently come across the issue too: building an application that uses Sqlite on Windows with Visual Studio and deploying it on an Ubuntu Server box for production.

The simplest solution I've found is using the Mono driver for Sqlite: **[Mono.Data.Sqlite](http://www.mono-project.com/SQLite)**.

Things could have been a little simpler but there is **[a bug with .Net 4.0](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2148)** that is not yet packaged in the official Mono releases.

So you'll have to compile Mono from source ([the general instructions are here](https://github.com/mono/mono)):

- first compile the whole Mono stuff
- you do not need to install it if you want to keep your current Mono setup
- copy the **Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll** library

Of course you can "cross-compile": I've built Mono on Ubuntu Server and used the dll in a Windows .Net project.

Then ensure you have **[the native Sqlite library](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html)** (sqlite3.dll for Windows and sqlite3.so for Linux) in your library path: for Windows I simply copied the sqlite3.dll next to the Mono.Data.Sqlite.dll assembly, for Linux it should work out of the box.

You project should then work seamlessly in both Windows/.Net and Linux/Mono environments.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve the naming differences using alias

```
#if (linux)
  using SqlCommand = Mono.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand;
#else
  using SqlCommand = System.Data.SQLite;
```

Using different assemblies for different builds is a more complex task i think.. you can have a look at the MSBuild documentation

Comment: What if the internal implementation(method and properties) of SqliteCommand and SQLite are different?

Comment: You are right, I assumed that all the 2 implementation inherits from System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand

Answer (score 1):

There is a fully managed [SQLite translation](http://code.google.com/p/managed-sqlite/). If you use that, then you could use the same DLL on Mono and Windows.

Another way to solve your issue is to create your own database-interface and then implement that interface once for Mono and one for Microsoft .NET in separate DLLs. (Basically the same way you create code that runs against different databases)

Comment: its based on SQLite 3.4.0, which is outdated and database will suffer incompatibility issues i guess

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the mono implementation of SQLite for both, Windows and Linux versions of your software. Just include the mono assembly for SQLite in your software package and refer to it locally.

As you can read [here](http://go-mono.com/forums/#nabble-td1505622) in the last post, you can use the managed way of mono solely in your code and need just to redistribute the native part for windows differently. But you do not have to mess with to managed implementations and redundand code through that.

Comment: so ill need to provide and include mono sqlite .so in windows build ?

Comment: well, i have to admit, it does not seem so simple.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source [Vici CoolStorage](http://viciproject.com/coolstorage) ORM library works on Windows (.NET), Mono (Mac,Linux and Windows) and MonoTouch (iPhone) using that platform's SQLite driver.

To use it on these different platforms, you don't have to change anything to your source code. Just recompile, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

IMO you should first try to find an implementation that works in both Windows and Linux. If that doesn't work, create an assembly that defines a common interface for SQLite and put all you "#if LINUX" code in that assembly. Then use that assembly in the main application to avoid cluttering the main app with all the # defines.

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite ADO.NET provider is actually a mixed-mode assembly, which contains the native SQLite library. This native library is not the same on Windows and Linux of course, so this provider doesn't work on Linux. However, there is a managed-only version of the provider (*SQLite-1.0.65.0-managedonly-binaries.zip* on the download page). So I *think* you just need to use this version of the provider, and provide the adequate native SQLite dynamic library along with it (.dll on Windows, .so on Linux)

Answer (score 0):

Some answers suggest the fully-managed [C# port of SQLite3](http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/). But, unfortunately, no release to date supports Linux or Mac OS X despite being compilable with the Mono C# compiler.

A future release will correctly run on those non-Windows platforms with the Mono runtime. WIth some caveats, the [source repository](http://code.google.com/r/stewartadcock-csharp-sqlite-updates/source) contains code that works.

Having said that, the [System.Data.SQLite](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) implementation available from sqlite.org works with both .Net and Mono, on Windows and non-Windows platforms. You just need to ensure that the app.config used by Mono at runtime maps the (C++) SQLite3 dll to the appropriate .so or .dylib library.  If you choose the "mixed-mode" version, then it should *just work* and you don't need to worry about separate dlls.

Comment: How do you make System.Data.SQLite work with Mono? It is not as simple as you describe unfortunately.